# ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential identity token have change If bundle id unchange in ios?

Tags: ios, swift

I have transfer app to another account but i not change bundle id of app. ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential identity token generate by bundle id and team id associated apple developer account. Could you let me know identity token changes if the bundle ID remains unchanged?